# RestSharp 401 Error, 200 on Other Clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, restsharp

I am trying to connect to a local nxwitness (Restful) server with restsharp using basic authentication. I am receiving a 401 error.

I receive a 200 on Boomerang in chrome, however in Postman I also receive a 401 error.

Here is my restsharp code.

```
        var client = new RestClient("http://192.168.42.42:7001")
        {
           Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username","password");
        };

        var request = new RestRequest("/ec2/getMediaServers/", Method.GET);
        //var request = new RestRequest("ec2/getMediaServers/", Method.GET); //also tried
        //var request = new RestRequest("ec2/getMediaServers", Method.GET);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request); //401
        var content = response.Content;
```

**Edit and Resolution**

It turns out the code was ok. Boomerang was using a cookie created in another tab. it was just a matter of creating a new nxwitness(api i was calling) account which had the necessary  permissions.

Comment: You can check in browser what headers has been passed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to set header in your client